# Mac Terminal Find command cannot see directory

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I use this command:
`find /Applications/MAMP "htdocs"`
And I can see loads of htdocs/files showing but the final outcome is "No such file or directory"
If I make it faster by writing `find /Applications/MAMP "htdocs" -type d` then No such file or directory also

Even though in the list I can see '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs'
Maybe I have misunderstood the use of the find command?? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use `-name htdocs`, then `htdocs` will be interpreted as *another* path to search in.

If `./htdocs` does not exist, you will get this error message.

Comment: Yes that works. I will need to read into the documentation more to develop my skills. Thanks